# Setting up R formulae environments and conversion context managers

Tags: python, rpy2

According to the [Rpy2 documentation](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/pandas.html), a context manager can be used to achieve the conversion to/from Pandas/R.  However, how should one set up the environment for formulae in the context manager?  For example, the following fails:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import rpy2.robjects as robjs
import rpy2.robjects.conversion as cv
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri, Formula

r_mass = importr("MASS")
r_stats = importr("stats")

# From MASS dose.p example
ldose = pd.Series(np.concatenate((np.arange(1, 6), np.arange(1, 6))))
numdead = pd.Series(np.array([1, 4, 9, 13, 18, 20, 0, 2, 6, 10, 12, 16]))
sex = pd.Series(np.repeat(["M", "F"], [6, 6]))
SF = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((numdead, 20 - numdead)),
                  columns=["numdead", "numalive"])
glm_fmla = Formula("SF ~ sex + ldose - 1")


with cv.localconverter(robjs.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
    glm_fmla.environment["SF"] = SF
    glm_fmla.environment["sex"] = sex
    glm_fmla.environment["ldose"] = ldose
    budworm_lg0 = robjs.r.glm(glm_fmla, family=r_stats.binomial)
```

with the message:

```py
RRuntimeError: Error in model.frame.default(formula = SF ~ sex + ldose - 1, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'SF'
```

using rpy2 3.3.6, and the latest R release on Linux.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions of type `RRuntimeError` relay errors, and their associated message, generated by R. Here the R code called (`glm()` and other R code it calls) ends with a complain that the value for `SF` is an R `list` and that this is an incompatible type.

In R, `data.frame` objects inherit from `list` so this may genuinely indicate that the R code does not accept a data like you have for the dependent variable.

We can check the type of the value for `SF`:

```
>>> tuple(glm_fmla.environment['SF'].rclass)
('data.frame',)
```

The target type for the conversion appear to be correct. We had a `pandas.DataFrame` converted to an R `data.frame`.

The R example for the function `MASS::dose.p()` defines `SF` like this:

```
numdead <- c(1, 4, 9, 13, 18, 20, 0, 2, 6, 10, 12, 16)
SF <- cbind(numdead, numalive = 20 - numdead)
```

This is not a `data.frame`:

```
> class(SF)
[1] "matrix"
```

Your code can be modified like this:

```
r_base = importr('base')
with cv.localconverter(robjs.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
    glm_fmla.environment["SF"] = base.as_matrix(SF)
    glm_fmla.environment["sex"] = sex
    glm_fmla.environment["ldose"] = ldose
    budworm_lg0 = robjs.r.glm(glm_fmla, family=r_stats.binomial)
```

**Note:** Your example is now failing with

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = SF ~ sex + ldose - 1, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'ldose')
```

You will easily fix it by ensuring that `ldose` and `SF` have the same number of observations (10, or 12):

```
>>> len(ldose)
10
>>> SF.shape
(12, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I wrongly assumed that the `data.frame` would be coerced to `matrix` on R's end, in addition to having mistakenly assigned wrong length to vectors with `np.arange`.  Extra care is needed with the types being passed back and forth!